# apt maven plugin fail to generate Q classes

Tags: maven-plugin, m2eclipse, apt, querydsl

I am fixing a legacy project that uses Querydsl apt. For some reason the [apt-maven-plugin](https://github.com/mysema/apt-maven-plugin/) started to fail. The only workaround I found was to use the alter ego [maven-processor-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-annotation-plugin/).

I have reinstalled maven, eclipse and M2E with not much success. The maven-apt-plugin is unable to create the Q classes under /target/generated-sources/metamodel.

edit: adding debug from maven

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.0.8:process from pl
ugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.0.8, parent: su
n.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6d9bf996]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.0.8:process' with
basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (s) logOnlyOnError = true
[DEBUG]   (s) outputDirectory = C:\DEV\myproject\mainstuff\mainstuff-jpa\target\generate
d-sources\metamodel
[DEBUG]   (s) pluginArtifacts = [com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:
1.0.8:, org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.7:compile, org.codehaus.ple
xus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.8:compile, backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concu
rrent:jar:3.1:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:compile
, junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile]
[DEBUG]   (s) processor = com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor
[DEBUG]   (s) project = MavenProject: com.yreham.mainstuff:mainstuff-jpa:1.0
 @ C:\DEV\myproject\mainstuff\mainstuff-jpa\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (s) sourceEncoding = ISO-8859-1
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Using build context: org.sonatype.plexus.build.incremental.DefaultBuildC
ontext@27bb2f11
[ERROR] C:\DEV\myproject\mainstuff\mainstuff-jpa\src\main\java\com\yreham\mainstuff\j
pa\queries\InstancesQuery.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
import com.yreham.mainstuff.jpa.entity.QCIEntity;
```

Some details of the config  m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.2.0.20120903-1050 org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e

java version "1.7.0_15"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_15-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

(The target build is Java 1.6)

Here's the old pom XML

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0.8</version>
<executions>
 <execution>
   <goals>
      <goal>process</goal>
   </goals>
  <configuration>
   <outputDirectory>${apt.target.dir}</outputDirectory>
   processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
   <logOnlyOnError>true</logOnlyOnError>
   </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

The new POM with bsc plugin

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId> 
<artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId> 
 <version>2.0.5</version> 
  <executions> 
   <execution> 
    <id>process</id> 
    <goals> 
      <goal>process</goal> 
    </goals> 
 <phase>generate-sources</phase> 
  <configuration>
  <outputDirectory>${apt.target.dir}</outputDirectory>
    <processors>
      <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
    </processors>                  
  </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions> 
 <dependencies> 
  <dependency> 
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> 
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId> 
       <version>1.2.0.Final</version> 
       </dependency> 
   </dependencies> 
</plugin>
```

Comment: Do you get any exception from apt-maven-plugin usage?

Comment: as per resquest below I am updating the question with the debug output. the plugin doesn't throw exception it only fails to find the Q* classes

Comment: Which Querydsl version do you use? Do you also use Spring Data? If yes, which version?

Comment: we are using querydsl 2.3.2. and no Spring.

Comment: Have you tried adding `target/generated-sources/annotations` to the build path manually?

Comment: I forgot this question, I'll put an answer below. see comments for people who may find this problem later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a JPA configuration problem. I didn't see it was using an Hibernate layer on top Querydsl. 
Since we moved to the Eclipse J2EE version and added M2E WTP http://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/, the jpa module was correctly reconfigured.

Answer (score 2):

Does your project build in command line?

If it doesn't, it'll most probably fail to build in eclipse too.

Now if CLI actually works, have you tried to install m2e-apt? It'll make annotation processing part of eclipse's incremental build process. See https://github.com/jbosstools/m2e-apt/ for more details.

Comment: I am updating the question because it fails on command line too.